# Segmentation Fault in Function Call

Tags: c++

So I've got my program to the point where it compiles, but upon calling up the other functions the program drops with a Segmentation Fault(core dumped) error.
Everything works until then. I'll add the entire code in case the setup is wrong (possible as I don't particularly understand pointers or passing values and such)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void discrim0(float a, float b, float c, float * root1, float * root2);
void discrimmore(float a, float b, float c, float * root1, float * root2);
void discrimless(float a, float b, float c, float * real, float * sqrtim);

int main()
{

 float discrim;
 float a;
 float b;
 float c;
 float * root1=0;
 float * root2=0;
 float * real=0;
 float * sqrtim=0;
 char cAgain;

 cout << "Welcome to the quadratic roots calculator." <<endl;

 do
 {
  do
  {

   cout << "Please enter the three coefficient values of the" <<endl;
   cout << "quadratic equation. The coefficient of x^2 must not"<<endl;
   cout << "be 0." <<endl;

   cin >> a >> b >> c;

   if(a==0)
   {
    cout << "The value you entered for the coefficient of x^2"<<endl;
    cout << "is not valid(0). Please enter a proper value."<<endl;
   }
  }while(a==0);


  discrim=(b*b)-4*a*c;

  if(discrim<0)
   {
    cout << "Your equation has two imaginary roots."<<endl;
    //error occurs here
    discrimless(a,b,c, real, sqrtim);
    cout << *real << " + " << *sqrtim << "i" << endl;
    cout << "and" << endl;
    cout << *real << " - " << *sqrtim << "i" << endl;
   }

   if(discrim==0)
   {
    cout << "Your equation two roots of the same value."<<endl;
    //error occurs here
    discrim0(a,b,c, root1, root2);
    cout << *root1 << " and " << *root2 << endl;
   }

   if(discrim>=0)
   {
    cout << "Your equation has two real roots, which are: "<<endl;
    //error occurs here
    discrimmore(a,b,c, root1, root2);
    cout << *root1 << " and " << *root2;
   }

   cout << "Would you like to run another calculation? Y/y/N/n"<<endl;
   cin >> cAgain;

  }while(cAgain=='Y'||cAgain=='y');

  return 0;
 }

 void discrim0(float a, float b, float c, float * root1, float * root2)
 {
  *root1= ((-b + sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/2*a);

  *root2= ((-b - sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/2*a);
 }

 void discrimless(float a, float b, float c, float * real, float * sqrtim)
 {
  *real= (-b)/(2*a);
  *sqrtim= (sqrt(-(b*b-4*a*c)))/(2*a);

 }

 void discrimmore(float a, float b, float c, float *  root1, float * root2)
 {
  *root1= ((-b + sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/2*a);

  *root2=((-b - sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/2*a);
 }
```

I marked in the code where it happens. Essentially it will tell you the number of roots and then crash. I understand the general idea of seg fault that I am trying to access memory I don't have or something to that effect, but I don't really know why it is occurring. Also please keep in mind that I don't really understand technical speak too well. Thanks.

Comment: Please construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than posting all of the code.

Comment: Don't use `float*`s... just use `float`s and have functions accept `float&` when they'll change one of the caller's values.  (You *could* get the code working with `float*`s, but it's not worth the grief.  The problem is that when you do things like `discrimless(a,b,c, real, sqrtim);`, the functions operate on `*real` which is meant to be a `float` pointed to by `real`, but your pointer was initialised to `0` (what's called a `nullptr`) and never aimed at an actual `float`.)

Comment: Same as Tony D, change the `float*` to just `float`. If anyone gives you an answer involving pointers for this particular program that would just promote bad practices. Instead change `discrimless(a,b,c, *real, *sqrtim);` to `discrimless(a,b,c, &real, &sqrtim);` and all pointers to normal values. If your intention was to learn about pointers, this is a bad example to attempt it

Comment: Time to learn how to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux) and to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Just to give some background I originally was using & but couldn't get some errors out of it which somehow pointers resolved it with some assistance from someone, had the code fully running, but later lost it and was trying to reproduce it. That's why I had it the way it was.Living in confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring pointers

```
float * root1=0;
float * root2=0;
float * real=0;
float * sqrtim=0;
```

and passing them to various functions without them pointing to valid memory.

Looking at the functions you have, you don't need to declare pointers. You need to use object and pass the addresses of those objects in the function calls.

```
float root1=0;  // Good to initialize them.
float root2=0;
float real=0;
float sqrtim=0;
```

and them call the function with the syntax:

```
discrim0(a,b,c, &root1, &root2);
```

Make similar changes to the calls to `discrimmore` and `discrimless`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float * root1=0;
float * root2=0;
float * real=0;
float * sqrtim=0;
```

You're declaring four pointers and you're never assigning them a valid memory address.